# Is there any specific reason to level up any specific character or all of your characters?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

With so many characters available it strikes me that you can just set up a core team and go about your day and ignore everybody else. Do you ever NEED specific characters to be level 50+ or is a core team of 10 or so characters that fill appropriate roles (physical, magical, healing, etc) sufficient for most purposes and you just have your pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reason to have multiple teams is to take advantage of the hp and exp boost from Record Synergy during time-limited events.

That said, early on it's probably best to focus on a smaller subset of your characters like you said, since a handful of level 50's is going to do better than a Synergized group of 25's.  I spend my handful of Memory Crystal Lodes - and 75%+ of my Growth Eggs - getting a few characters of each role as high as I can get them.

Note that as your characters start reaching level 50, earning their Memory Crystals becomes useful even if you don't plan to keep leveling them right now, because a character that breaks their level cap immediately earns a unique Record Materia, and only characters who've broken the cap can earn more Record Materia in play.